# Please explain how to do this, base e

Tags: exponential-function

Express $ 3^X$, $x^\pi$, $x^{\sin x} $ using base $e$.

Comment: $$A^B = e^{B\ln A}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The most basic properties of logarithems tell you that $A = e^{\ln A}$.  Therefore
$$
A^B = \Big( e^{\ln A} \Big)^B = e^{B\ln A}.
$$